# Bash: optionally passing arguments to a command

Tags: bash, shell-script, bash-scripting, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to add arguments to a command call depend on another variable. Please look at the shell scripting code:

```
curl \
  $([ -z "${title}" ] || echo --data-urlencode title=${title}) \
  http://example.com
```

In the example, if `title` is given not null, an argument will be added to `curl`.

This does not work correctly if `title` contains spaces. Also I couldn't surround `$(...)` with quotations, because if `title` is null, it will yield an unexpected empty argument to `curl`.

What should I do to make it work as expect.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I've solved the problem with the bash `${var:+...}` syntax, ([reference](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050#I_only_want_to_pass_options_if_the_runtime_data_needs_them)).

The script now changes to

```
curl \
    ${title:+ --data-urlencode "title=${title}"} \
    http://example.com
```

which works perfectly.

Also see:

- [Bash - function with optional arguments and missing logic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13206311/1232832)
- [How to write a bash script that takes optional input arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9332802/1232832)

Comment: `${var:-word}             # if var is defined AND NOT EMPTY, use var; otherwise, "word"
similarly for ${var:+word} etc.`
, plus `${var+word}             # if var is defined, use "word"; otherwise, nothing`

means that… if variable is defined, use the section following the `+`

Comment: @ijoseph this is opposite of what the question is about