# How to conditionally add flags to curl?

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I'm trying to conditionally add a header to a curl command.

This is my initial attempt:

```sh
# Set Auth Header
if [ $IS_PUBLIC == 0 ]; then
  AUTH_HEADER="-H 'authorization: Bearer $TOKEN'"
fi

# Get Version
VERSION=$(curl -s $AUTH_HEADER "https://api.github.com/repos/$REPOSITORY/releases/latest" | jq -r '.tag_name')
```

`echo $VERSION` output: `null`, which means the `$AUTH_HEADER` was not successfully inserted.

Next I tried two solutions based on answers to this question [How to conditionally add flags to shell scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42985611/how-to-conditionally-add-flags-to-shell-scripts).

```sh
args=(
  -s
  "https://api.github.com/repos/$REPOSITORY/releases/latest"
)

# Set Auth Header
if [ $IS_PUBLIC == 0 ]; then
  args+=("-H 'authorization: Bearer $TOKEN'")
fi

# Get Version
VERSION=$(curl "${args[@]}" | jq -r '.tag_name')
```

`echo $VERSION` output: empty string. Calling `curl "${args[@]}"` by itself also outputs an empty string.

```sh
# Set Auth Header
AUTH_HEADER="-H 'authorization: Bearer $TOKEN'"

# Get Version
VERSION=$(curl -s ${IS_PUBLIC:+"$AUTH_HEADER"} "https://api.github.com/repos/$REPOSITORY/releases/latest" | jq -r '.tag_name')
```

This results in the same output as the second example.

I was surprised that I could not get it to work since the answers from which I got these solutions have many upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

With a small change, the third solution works:

```sh
# Set Auth Header
AUTH_HEADER="authorization: Bearer $TOKEN"

# Get Version
VERSION=$(curl -s ${IS_PUBLIC:+ -H "$AUTH_HEADER"} "https://api.github.com/repos/$REPOSITORY/releases/latest" | jq -r '.tag_name')
```

Found the decisive clue here: [Bash: optionally passing arguments to a command](https://superuser.com/questions/802539/bash-optionally-passing-arguments-to-a-command).

Answer (score 0):

The second one should work if you use correct quoting while building the array. You want one array element per command argument, and *don't* embed quotes in the values. Basically, when building the array, you quote the same way you would directly on the comand line.

```
args=(
  -s
  "https://api.github.com/repos/$REPOSITORY/releases/latest"
)

# Set Auth Header
if [ $IS_PUBLIC == 0 ]; then
  args+=(-H "authorization: Bearer $TOKEN")    # Corrected quoting here
fi

# Get Version
VERSION=$(curl "${args[@]}" | jq -r '.tag_name')
```